# How To Show And Hide Input Fields Based On Radio Button Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code to show input fields depending on radio selection like:

## SCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

</script>
```

## HTML

```
Yes
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"/>No
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"/>
<br>
<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden">If yes, explain:
    <input type='text' id='yes' name='yes'/>
    <br>What can we do to accommodate you?
        <input type='text' id='acc' name='acc'/>
</div>
   other 3
<input type='text' id='other3' name='other3'>
<br>
    other 4
<input type='text' id='other4' name='other4'>
<br>
```

However I would like input fields to be hidden (like on the image), and make they do not use any space until radio button is selected, when radio is selected show them with fade effect...

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/12/):

[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Replace all instances of `visibility` style to `display`

```
display:none //to hide
display:block //to show
```

Here's updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/16/

You can do it using Mootools or jQuery functions to slide up/down but if you don't need animation effect it's probably too much for what you need.

CSS display is a faster and simpler approach.

Answer (score 12):

```
***This will work.........
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
}
function yesnoCheck() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('redhat1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('aix1').style.display = 'none';
    } 
    else if(document.getElementById('noCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('redhat1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('aix1').style.display = 'none';
   }
}
function yesnoCheck1() {
   if(document.getElementById('redhat').checked) {
       document.getElementById('redhat1').style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById('aix1').style.display = 'none';
    }
   if(document.getElementById('aix').checked) {
       document.getElementById('aix1').style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById('redhat1').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Select os :<br>
windows
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"/>Unix
<input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"/>
<br>
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
Windows 2008<input type="radio" name="win" value="2008"/>
Windows 2012<input type="radio" name="win" value="2012"/>
</div>
<div id="ifNo" style="display:none">
Red Hat<input type="radio" name="unix" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck1();"value="2008" 

id="redhat"/>
AIX<input type="radio" name="unix" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck1();"  
value="2012" id="aix"/>
</div>
<div id="redhat1" style="display:none">
Red Hat 6.0<input type="radio" name="redhat" value="2008" id="redhat6.0"/>
Red Hat 6.1<input type="radio" name="redhat" value="2012" id="redhat6.1"/>
</div>
<div id="aix1" style="display:none">
aix 6.0<input type="radio" name="aix" value="2008" id="aix6.0"/>
aix 6.1<input type="radio" name="aix" value="2012" id="aix6.1"/
</div>
</body> 
</html>***
```

Comment: I just wanted to tell you that your solution already helped me multiple times! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can do with Very Simple Step

```
$(':radio[id=radio1]').change(function() {
   $("#yes").removeClass("none");
   $("#no").addClass("none");


});
$(':radio[id=radio2]').change(function() {
   $("#no").removeClass("none");
   $("#yes").addClass("none");

});
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to also set the height of the element to 0 when it's hidden. I ran into this problem while using jQuery, my solution was to set the height and opacity to 0 when it's hidden, then change height to auto and opacity to 1 when it's un-hidden.

I'd recommend looking at jQuery. It's pretty easy to pick up and will allow you to do things like this a lot more easily.

```
$('#yesCheck').click(function() {
    $('#ifYes').slideDown();
});
$('#noCheck').click(function() {
    $('#ifYes').slideUp();
});
```

It's slightly better for performance to change the CSS with jQuery and use CSS3 animations to do the dropdown, but that's also more complex. The example above should work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Just FYI he is using Mootools and not jQuery :)

Comment: The question is tagged with jQuery and I found it in the jQuery question list, so I gave him a jQuery answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `display:none/block`, instead of `visibility`, and add a `margin-top/bottom` for the space you want to see ONLY when the inputs are shown

```
 function yesnoCheck() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
           document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
           document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

and your HTML line for the `ifYes` tag

```
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none;margin-top:3%;">If yes, explain:
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:none` to not show the items, then with JQuery you can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` to hide/unhide the elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp

Answer (score 1):

Using the `visibility` property only affects the visibility of the elements on the page; they will still be there in the page layout. To completely remove the elements from the page, use the `display` property.

```
display:none // for hiding
display:block // for showing
```

Make sure to change your css file to use display instead of visibility too.

As for the javascript (this is not jQuery), make sure you hide the options by default when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
    }

    function yesnoCheck() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        } 
        else {
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

</script>
```

If you haven't done so already, I would recommend taking a look at jQuery. jQuery code is much clearer and easier to write and understand.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Check() {
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';

   }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
Select os :
<br>
Two
<input type="radio" onclick="Check();" value="Two" name="categor`enter code here`y" id="yesCheck"/>One
<input type="radio" onclick="Check();" value="One"name="category"/>
<br>
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none" >
Three<input type="radio" name="win" value="Three"/>
Four<input type="radio" name="win" value="Four"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone wants a solution where only the **input** field displays when a radio button is selected using pure Javascript, here it is:

```js
function yesnoCheck() {
    yes1 = document.getElementById('yes')
    yes2 = document.getElementById('acc')
    
    no1 = document.getElementById('other3')
    no2 = document.getElementById('other4')
    
    if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
        yes1.type = yes2.type = 'text';
        no1.type = no2.type = 'hidden';
    } else {
        no1.type = no2.type = 'text';
        yes1.type = yes2.type = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

```html
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck"/>

No <input type="radio" onclick="yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"/>

<br>

<input type='hidden' id='yes' name='yes' placeholder='If yes, explain:'/>
<input type='hidden' id='acc' name='acc' placeholder='What can we do to accommodate you?'/>

<input type='hidden' id='other3' name='other3' placeholder='other 3'>
<input type='hidden' id='other4' name='other4' placeholder='other 4'>
```

Comment: I'm also aware that I'm not answering the question posted, but based on the title this was what I wanted when I was looking for solutions just the other day...