# Why is this hide not working?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621515/how-to-show-and-hide-input-fields-based-on-radio-button-selection)

I have this in my form;

```
       <div class="form-check">
            {!! Form::checkbox('yesPlease', 1, null, ['id' => 'yesCheck']) !!}
        </div>
        <div class="check-label">
        Yes please.
        </div>
        <div id="ifYes" style="display:none">
            <div class="form-check">
                {!! Form::checkbox('alsoYes', 1, null) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="check-label">
                Also yes.
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this in my script;

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function yesnoCheck() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        } else
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        }

    </script>
```

However, when you select 'yesCheck', 'ifYes' does not get display:block.

Seems pretty simple, what am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: here is the update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QAaHP/2236/ .. it works btw

Comment: That did it! Thanks.