# HTML Input display not changing with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I hate to beat a dead horse with this question but I am not having any luck getting two HTML Input elements to show when a checkbox is checked. I have been through multiple pages on here related to this issue with the last one being [How To Show And Hide Input Fields Based On Radio Button Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621515/how-to-show-and-hide-input-fields-based-on-radio-button-selection). Here is the code

```
function f1() {
    var mycheck = document.getElementById("isevent").checked;
    var myevent = document.getElementById("eventname");
    var mycampaign = document.getElementById("campaign");

    if (mycheck === true) {

        myevent.style.display = 'normal';
        mycampaign.style.display = 'normal';
        alert("Myevent's visibility is " + myevent.style.display);

    } else {
        myevent.style.display = 'none';
        mycampaign.style.display = 'none';

    }
}
```

I can see from the alert that the function is being called by the checkbox but the display value doesn't change. Here is the fiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/352hjrwo/12/

What am I missing?

Comment: Try making the style.display = 'block' instead of 'normal'

Comment: There's no such display as normal. Try using `initial` instead.

Comment: Instead of `display: normal` use `display: block`

Comment: Display values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Such simple things often get looked over. I changed from normal to block and everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `normal` to `block` ;)

```js
function f1() {
            var mycheck = document.getElementById("isevent").checked;
            var myevent = document.getElementById("eventname");
            var mycampaign = document.getElementById("campaign");
            
            if (mycheck === true) {
              
                    myevent.style.display = 'block';
                    mycampaign.style.display = 'block';
                alert("Myevent's visibility is " + myevent.style.display);

            } else {
                    myevent.style.display = 'none';
                    mycampaign.style.display = 'none';

            }
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="isevent" runat="server" class="rcorners" onclick="javascript:f1()" />&nbsp;Staffed Event?
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="eventname" class="rcorners input" runat="server" placeholder="Event Name" style="display:none;" maxlength="128" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="campaign" runat="server" class="rcorners input" placeholder="Campaign" maxlength="64" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use display = block you would be fine.

HTML

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="isevent" runat="server" class="rcorners" onchange="javascript:f1(this)" />&nbsp;Staffed Event?
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="eventname" class="rcorners input" runat="server" placeholder="Event Name" style="display:none;" maxlength="128" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="campaign" runat="server" class="rcorners input" placeholder="Campaign" maxlength="64" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    function f1(element) {
        var myevent = document.getElementById("eventname");
        var mycampaign = document.getElementById("campaign");

        if (element.checked) {

                myevent.style.display = 'block';
                mycampaign.style.display = 'block';
                    alert("Myevent's visibility is " + myevent.style.display);

        } else {
                myevent.style.display = 'none';
                mycampaign.style.display = 'none';

        }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Just replace normal with block. Display property doesn't have normal value.

http://jsfiddle.net/352hjrwo/19/

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="isevent" runat="server" class="rcorners" onclick="javascript:f1()" />&nbsp;Staffed Event?
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="eventname" class="rcorners input" runat="server" placeholder="Event Name" style="display:none;" maxlength="128" />
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="campaign" runat="server" class="rcorners input" placeholder="Campaign" maxlength="64" style="display:none;" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function f1() {
            var mycheck = document.getElementById("isevent").checked;
            var myevent = document.getElementById("eventname");
            var mycampaign = document.getElementById("campaign");

            if (mycheck === true) {

                    myevent.style.display = 'block';
                    mycampaign.style.display = 'block';
                alert("Myevent's visibility is " + myevent.style.display);

            } else {
                    myevent.style.display = 'none';
                    mycampaign.style.display = 'none';

            }
}
</script>
```